# How to find all Restaurants in a given location iOS

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'm doing this small project for myself to get acquainted to mapkit, but I can't find any resources on this question that don't involve integrating with the foursquare API (which I don't want to do).

I need to do this:

Do a local search with the query "Restaurant"

Return back all Restaurants with annotations on the map within a certain radius

Fill up a tableview with the main information about each location.

Comment: Sounds like either homework or a take-home assignment for an application.

Comment: @nhgrif it's just a small app I'm building for myself, thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a fun and handy app.  I could use that about 13 times a week.  :D

Comment: @MichaelGaskill You might be interested in [this startup's idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Maps) then :D

Answer (score 2):

Provide the term you want to search for as the natural language parameter "restaurant".

```
func searchBy(naturalLanguageQuery: String, region: MKCoordinateRegion, coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D, completionHandler: (response: MKLocalSearchResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void) {

    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = naturalLanguageQuery
    request.region = region

    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
    search.startWithCompletionHandler { response, error in
        guard let response = response else {
            completionHandler(response: nil, error: error)

            return
        }

        completionHandler(response: response, error: error)
    }
}
```